# sum of all positive integral values of $a\;,$ for which equation $\lfloor x \rfloor ^3+x-a=0$ has solution

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> The sum of all positive integral values of $a\;,$ Where $a\in \left[1,1500\right]$
>
> for which the equation $\lfloor x \rfloor ^3+x-a=0$ has solution, Where $\lfloor x \rfloor $ Represent floor of $x$

$\bf{My\; Try::}$ Given $\lfloor x \rfloor ^3+x-a=0\Rightarrow x=\underbrace{a-\lfloor x \rfloor^3}_{\bf{integer\; quantity}}$

So Here  $x$ must be an $\bf{Integer\; quantity.}$

Now How can I solve after that, Help Required, Thanks

Comment: So you have the equation $x^3 + x -a=0, x\in \mathbb{Z}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\lfloor x \rfloor ^3+x-a=0$$
$a\in \mathbb Z \Rightarrow x \in Z$
$$x^3+x=a$$
$$x(x^2+1)=a$$
$a\in[1;1500]$

Then $2\le x\le11$

If $x=2$ then $a=10$

If $x=3$ then $a=3\cdot10=30$

...

If $x=11$ then $a=11\cdot(11^2+1)=1342$

Answer (score 2):

As you noted, we must have $x
 $ integer, hence the equation is $$n^{3}+n=a,\, n\in\mathbb{N}
 $$ and so the problem can be seen as to find $$\sum_{n=1}^{11}\left(n^{3}+n\right)
 $$ since $11^{3}+11=1342,\,12^{3}+12=1740.
 $ So $$\sum_{n=1}^{11}\left(n^{3}+n\right)=\sum_{n=1}^{11}n^{3}+\sum_{n=1}^{11}n=4422.$$